# Change lambda expression return type to Unit

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, android-viewpager, bottomnavigationview

I am using Kotlin language and I have Bottom Navigation View in my app. I want to implement setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener method for changing the my viewPager.

However when I implement it gives me error which is 'change lambda expression return type to Unit' . I don't understand why. I checked on internet, some people use same lines code with me but they don't get error. I will share screenshot of error.

Also when I change setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener  to etOnNavigationItemReselectedListener it doesn't give error. However I need to selectItemListener not Reselect .

This is my method.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `true` in your lambda, right after the `when` statement. [This functional interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) requires you to return a Boolean value. The last expression of a lambda is the return value.

For less repetitive code, you may consider modifying it as shown:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    val page = when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.navigator_main -> 0
        R.id.navigator_search_food -> 1
        R.id.navigator_list_of_week -> 2
        R.id.navigator_for_students -> 3
        else -> -1
    }
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(page)
    true
}
```